# How to hide oembed links from wordpress excerpt?

Tags: wordpress

the_excerpt() function shows all oembeded links.

In this case is about a youtube video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP3EF.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following code to the functions.php file (backing up the file first just in case you break the page):

```
function remove_links($text) 
{
    if ('' == $text ) 
    {
        $pattern = '~http://[^\s]*~i'; //what we want to remove, the http link
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'remove_links');
```

This will override the default excerpt() function and look for the link and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Howli's answer, here's a modified version that also trims the excerpt and applies the proper filters:

```
function tect_excerpt( $text ) {
    if ( '' == $text ) {
        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

        $text = preg_replace( '~http(s)?://[^\s]*~i', '', $text ); // removes URLs

        $text = apply_filters( 'the_content', $text );
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
        $excerpt_length = apply_filters( 'excerpt_length', 20 ); // default: 55
        $excerpt_more = apply_filters( 'excerpt_more', ' ' . '[&hellip;]' );
        $text = wp_trim_words( $text, $excerpt_length, $excerpt_more );
    }
    return $text;
}

remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt' );
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'tect_excerpt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `wp_filter_nohtml_kses` function:

```
echo wp_filter_nohtml_kses(get_the_excerpt());
```

which will remove the `<a href="http://somelink.com">` and `</a>` opening and closing tags